# Test whether the given sequence of function is uniform convergence in $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Check the uniform convergence of the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=n\ln \left(\frac{1+nx}{nx}\right)$ on $(0,\infty)$.

I have found that the pointwise limit of the sequence of functions is $f(x)=\frac 1x$. I'm stuck proving uniform convergence. I am unable to find $\displaystyle M_n=\sup_{x\in (0,\infty)}\left|n\ln \left(\frac{1+nx}{nx}\right)-\frac 1x\right|$.

Any hints, please?

Comment: Are you sure it converges uniformly (and you have to prove it) or you have to find that out?

Comment: I am not sure, I want to check whether it is uniform or not.

Comment: It looks like it converges uniformly on $[1,\infty)$, but it does not on $(0,1)$

Comment: Why not in $(0,1)$ ? Can you please give more detail ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convergence is not uniform on any interval of the form $(0,a)$. Note that

$$n\ln \left(\frac{1+nx}{nx}\right)-\frac 1x = n\ln \left(\frac{1+nx}{nx}\right)-n\ln e^{\frac{1}{nx}} = n\ln \left(\frac{1+nx}{nxe^{\frac{1}{nx}} }\right),$$

and with $x = 1/n \in (0,1)$,

$$\sup_{x\in (0,\infty)}\left|n\ln \left(\frac{1+nx}{nx}\right)-\frac 1x\right| \geqslant \left|n\ln \left(\frac{1+n\cdot \frac{1}{n}}{n\cdot \frac{1}{n}\cdot e^{\frac{1}{n\cdot \frac{1}{n}}} }\right)\right|= n \ln \frac{e}{2} \underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow \infty$$